# Player detecting wall in array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want my player 'P' to be able to move around the map, but not move onto or past the walls. The code will work fine until I implement an if statement to check for walls.

My thought process to doing this was if the player moves in a direction, check if there's any walls in that direction first. If there is a wall, then let the player know.
When i did this, many problems occurred. The player will sometimes be able to detect the wall, and sometimes it doesn't. For example if i first run the program and move to the right 'e', it'll let me know that there is a wall, but once i move to the left 'w' and move back to the right, it'll go onto the wall.
Also moving up 'n' and down 's' is a problem as it goes up twice, rather then once.

Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

```
bool running = true;
int px = 2;
int py = 7;

char player = 'P';
//map
char map[8][8] = {
    { '#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#' },
    { '#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#' },
    { '#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#' },
    { '#','#','#',' ','#',' ',' ','#' },
    { '#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#' },
    { '#',' ','#','#','#',' ',' ','#' },
    { '#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#' },
    { '#','#',' ','#','#','#','#','#' }
};

// print map
void printMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (j == px && i == py) {
                cout << 'P';
            }
            else {
                cout << map[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
// player movement
void playerMove() {
    char move;

    cin >> move;
    if (move == 'e') {
        if (map[py][++px] == '#') { 
            cout << "there's a wall here!";
        }
        else {
            map[py][px] = ' ';
            map[py][++px] = player;
            system("cls");
            printMap();

        }
        
    }
    if (move == 'w') {
        if (map[py][--px] == '#') {
            cout << "there's a wall here!";
        }
        else {
            map[py][px] = ' ';
            map[py][--px] = player;
            system("cls");
            printMap();
        }
        
    }
    if (move == 'n') {
        if (map[--py][px] == '#') {
            cout << "there's a wall here!";
        }
        else {
            map[py][px] = ' ';
            map[--py][px] = player;
            system("cls");
            printMap();
        }
        
    }
    if (move == 's') {
        if (map[++py][px] == '#') {
            cout << "there's a wall here!";
        }
        else {
            map[py][px] = ' ';
            map[++py][px] = player;
            system("cls");
            printMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (map[py][++px]...` you don't want that. try `px+1`.

Comment: Your `playerMove()` function doesn't have any bounds-checking.

Comment: Your printmap wisely can show the player without the player (or "empty") being written into the map. So, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely how you check for wall colisions.

For example if we look at `map[py][++px] == '#'` we see that you modify `px`, so even if that position is a wall the player position is modifed.

This also leads to problems in the `else` part, as you then "clear" the position where the player isn't, as well as modify `px` *again*.

Solve it by using addition instead: `map[py][px + 1] == '#'`.

And as I already mentioned, add bounds-checking to make sure that e.g. `px + 1` isn't out of bounds.

Comment: You are right, but the funny thing is that once the wall checking is fixed, the bounds checking is only needed at the wall gap on the lower edge of the map.